# React-native scrollview onScroll call function to render more elements

Tags: javascript, react-native, infinite-scroll

So I've implemented my own `infinite scroll` type thingo with `<ScrollView onScroll={}>` and am having trouble when it comes to determining if the user has scrolled halfway down the screen. My if statement inside the `handlescroll` function is sometimes triggered simultaneously (Depending on how much I scroll past halfway) if I scroll past halfway.

Has anyone done anything similar to this, if you have could you provide me with some insight to how you achieved it.

Here is my scrollview, it simply holds many post components.

```
return (  
      <ScrollView key={"scrollview_1"} onScroll={this.handleScroll.bind(this)}>
        { postComponents }
      </ScrollView>
)


handleScroll (event: Object) {
    console.log(event.nativeEvent.contentOffset.y);
    const offset = event.nativeEvent.contentOffset.y;
    const screenHeight = Dimensions.get('window').height;

    const {FeedActions,} = this.props;
    const {nextUrl,} = feed;

    // Somehow figure out a way to check if past halfway only once 
    var x = (offset % screenHeight/2);
    if( x > 0 && x < 40){
      // Run API call get more posts, then render the new components
      FeedActions.getMorePosts(nextUrl, true);
    }

  }
```

I've also found that if they scroll past halfway & only scroll a little bit past `0 (offset%screenheight/2)`, my `FeedActions.getMorePosts` function will run again. To fix this I am thinking of implementing a `state` which will hold an array of the past screen heights. Inside my if statement I will then check to see if I have already passed any screen heights in my state array.

Comment: Wouldn't using ListView instead of ScrollView be better for your use-case? You could use methods like `onEndReached`

Comment: @Bhullnatik - I've never used it before. I'll look into it though